# Can the Excel 'freeze pane' feature be implemented in HTML?

Tags: html

i want to fix first row of table and this must work in IE 6 , 7, 8 and mozilla 3.o above
and this should be done with single table only, means the header row and other rows should lie in the same table.
can anyone provide me the source code for this??? thanks to all , helping me out.

As we implement in excel , the freeze pane scenario, i want to do the same in html , and the above requirements are the same.

Comment: Your question is too unclear o answer. Please provide more info on the requirement.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "fix first row of table" Is it broken, or do you want to 'fix it' in place. It's not clear how this could apply to an HTML table.

Comment: I clearly agree with adamantium and pavium. You really have not defined the parameters of your question. What does "fix" entail? Considering you mentioned a header (presumably a table header?), is that what you want to "fix", or the first row (tbody, tr?!). Make sense?

Comment: It seems very clear to me.  Fix it in place is what he means.

Comment: By the way, there are ways, sadly, none work with my project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are actually looking for a grid component jquery have [one](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), the ExtJs`s [one](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html). With this your user would always see column headers and would be able to page, order, group the data (if you implement those in the backend).

After for doing that in HTML I never hear a solution but I am not a HTML guru.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/FreezePanes.aspx

you can find the solution by visiting above url...